# Dynamic Directive ng-focus

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

My directive for ng-focus.

Edit: I was told there is existing core ng-focus. as i am very new to angular I don't see ng-focus as an option. As in fig below. Also it does not work

[image]

```
var ngControlMod = angular.module('ngControlModule', []);
ngControlMod.directive('ngFocus', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.ngFocus, function (val) {
                if (angular.isDefined(val) && val) {
                    $timeout(function () { element[0].focus(); });
                }
            }, true);

            element.bind('blur', function () {
                if (angular.isDefined(attrs.ngFocusLost)) {
                    scope.$apply(attrs.ngFocusLost);
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Here is how I am using in in my view

```
<table id="tblMyTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>My Dropdown</th>
            <th>My Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="ca in myList">
            <td>
                <select name="select_{{ca.ID}}" ng-model="ca.List" 
                ng-options="corr as corr.caText for corr in caList track by corr.caValue"
                ng-change="GetData(ca, ca.List)">
                    <option value="">--Select--</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="Date_{{ca.ID}}" ng-focus="isFocus_{{ca.ID}}" 
                date-picker="" ng-model="ca.caDate"
                placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" />
            </td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
 </table>
```

The idea is, if a user selects an option in dropdown the focus should automatically move to date in that row.
To achieve this I have added an ID as an identifier in attribute "name" for the html control in table row and in my controller

```
$scope.GetData= function (ca, Selected) {
    var propName = "isFocus_" + ca.ID;
    $scope[propName] = true;
}
```

After all the coding the result is not consistent. it works sometimes and other times it does . And I can't figure out the reason. Also I am getting this error

```
angular.js:14700 Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' is an 
unexpected token at column 9 of the expression [isFocus_{{ca.QuesID}}] 
starting at [{{ca.QuesID}}].
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.6/$parse/syntax?p0=%7B&p1=is%20an%20unexpected%20token&p2=9&p3=isFocus_%7B%7Bca.QuesID%7D%7D&p4=%7B%7Bca.QuesID%7D%7D
at angular.js:116
at AST.throwError (angular.js:15258)
at AST.ast (angular.js:15008)
at Parser.parse (angular.js:16350)
at $parse (angular.js:16496)
at Object.compile (angular.js:27337)
at applyDirectivesToNode (angular.js:9737)
at compileNodes (angular.js:9097)
at compileNodes (angular.js:9109)
at compileNodes (angular.js:9109) "<input name="Date_{{ca.ID}}" ng-focus="isFocus_{{ca.ID}}" date-picker="" ng-model="ca.caDate" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" />"
```

Comment: Be aware that adding  a custom `ng-focus` directive will not replace the existing core `ng-focus`. The $compile service will instantiate both the new custom directive and the existing core [`ng-focus` directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngFocus).

Comment: @ georgeawg please check edit. Also more information will be helpful. As i am very new to angularjs

Comment: You need to choose a new name for your directive that is not `ng-focus` like maybe `my-focus`. Your directive as written has alot of problems but most importantly naming it `ng-focus` is just plain wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Be aware that adding  a custom `ng-focus` directive will not replace the existing core `ng-focus`. The [$compile service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) will instantiate both the new custom directive and the existing core [`ng-focus` directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngFocus).

Avoid using the `ng-` prefix for custom directives. The `ng-` prefix is reserved for core directives. For more information, see [AngularJS Wiki - Best Practices](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Dev-Guide%3A-Best-Practices).

---

```
<input name="Date_{{ca.ID}}"  ̶n̶g̶-̶f̶o̶c̶u̶s̶=̶"̶i̶s̶F̶o̶c̶u̶s̶_̶{̶{̶c̶a̶.̶I̶D̶}̶}̶"̶
  ng-focus="'isFocus_'+ca.ID" 
  date-picker="" ng-model="ca.caDate"
  placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" />
```

> Why mixing interpolation and expressions is bad practice:
>
> - It increases the complexity of the markup
> - There is no guarantee that it works for every directive, because interpolation itself is a directive. 
>     If another directive accesses attribute data before interpolation has run, it will get the raw interpolation markup and not data.
> - It impacts performance, as interpolation adds another watcher to the scope.
> - Since this is not recommended usage, we do not test for this, and changes to AngularJS core may break your code.
>
> [— AngularJS Developer Guide - Interpolation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation#why-mixing-interpolation-and-expressions-is-bad-practice-)

Comment: but this does not solve the problem. without {{}} ca.ID never gets resolved into its value. in other words in developers tool if u inspect the element ng-focus resolves as ng-focus="'isFocus_'+ca.ID" instead of ng-focus="caDate_29". this 29 separates the date element from other dates in the table and is suppose to set focus on the date with ID 29.